# Getting the Count In a single Table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to get the Club_ID of all the clubs that have more than one member;

Here is the sql:

```
CREATE  TABLE `Members` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Club_ID` INT NULL ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


INSERT INTO `Members` (`Club_ID`, `Name`) VALUES ('1', 'Jim');
INSERT INTO `Members` (`Club_ID`, `Name`) VALUES ('2', 'John');
INSERT INTO `Members` (`Club_ID`, `Name`) VALUES ('1', 'Bill');
INSERT INTO `Members` (`Club_ID`, `Name`) VALUES ('3', 'Stan');
INSERT INTO `Members` (`Club_ID`, `Name`) VALUES ('4', 'David');
INSERT INTO `Members` (`Club_ID`, `Name`) VALUES ('1', 'Tony');
INSERT INTO `Members` (`Club_ID`, `Name`) VALUES ('5', 'Oscar');
```

This should return Only Club_ID =1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT COUNT(*), Club_ID
    FROM Members
GROUP BY Club_ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Club_ID from Members group by Club_ID having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select club_id
from members
group by club_id
having count(distinct id) >= 2
```